# Python interactive shell in Maximo?

Tags: python, jython, maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1, is there a way to execute Python/Jython scripts on demand?

---

For example, in other software such as ArcGIS Desktop, there is a window in the application called the Python Window:

[image]

In the ArcGIS python window, I can write any sort of script I want.

- For example, I can write a script that **loops through records in a table** and updates values based on certain criteria. And I can execute it on demand.

---

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Maximo? Maybe in Eclipse?

Comment: There is no Python interactive shell in Maximo. You would have to create a script and tie it to a button-action launch point, or maybe an escalation or cron task that you control on demand, or maybe a REST action that you trigger on demand. You could then press your button (or whatever you tied it to) to get your constantly-changed script to run. You would also have to make good use of logging and look at the logs to get any feedback. It's not pretty for real-time, one-off scripts like this, but then the system is meant for more repeatable, trackable tasks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported, but you can create and grant yourself an EXECUTE sig option in the autoscript application. This will enable an Execute action, allowing you to execute a script on demand. However, because no launch point was used to provide context, implicit variables and other context that you may be used to will not be available.

"On Demand Autoscript" is what I call a script that I develop with the intention of being executed from that Execute action. I have written On Demand scripts for doing things like resynchronizing nested workflows or preparing our data for an upgrade. On Demand scripts, though created the same way, are different from what the 7.6 documentation calls "Library scripts" in that, even though Library scripts aren't (necessarily) called from their own Launch Points, the script that calls them does usually provide some context / implicit variables.

An On Demand Autoscript usually looks something like this, which you can look up documentation on in the Maximo API JavaDocs.

```py
from psdi.server import MXServer
server = MXServer.getMXServer()
security = server.lookup("SECURITY")
userInfo = security.getSystemUserInfo()

mboSet = server.getMboSet("SOMEOBJECT", userInfo)
try:
    mboSet.setWhere("somecol = 'somevalue'")
    mbo = mboSet.moveFirst()
    while mbo:
        print "do something with mbo %s: %s" % (
            mbo.getUniqueIdentifer(), mbo.getString("DESCRIPTION"))

        mbo = mboSet.moveNext()

    if "applicable":
        mboSet.save()

finally:
    if not mboSet.isClosed():
        mboSet.close()
```

From the above, it should be plain that you can easily "write a script that loops through records in a table and updates values based on certain criteria. And I can execute it on demand."

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a script -- even without launch point -- from any Java class (within maximo) using this piece of code:

```
ScriptDriverFactory.getInstance().getScriptDriver(ScriptName).runScript(ScriptName, Context);
```

...where `Context` is a hashmap for all variables that might be needed in the script.

Answer (score 1):

*To build on @Preacher's answer:*

Instructions for running an automation script on-demand (adding the EXECUTE sig option):

1. Application Designer --> AUTOSCRIPT:

   - Create an EXECUTE sig option (Add/Modify Signature Options)
   - Option: EXECUTE
   - Description: Execute Script
   - Advanced Signature Options: None
2. Ensure that your security group has that EXECUTE sig option in the Automation Scripts application:

   - (It might be enabled by default)
   - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blkBW.png)
3. Log out of Maximo and back in again (to update your cached permissions with the change that was just made).
4. Create an automation script

   - Without launch points?
   - Automation Scripts application --> Create --> Script
5. Open the automation script.
6. The Execute Script action will appear in the left pane. Use it to run automation scripts on demand.

   - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggNnR.png)

Comment: The upgrade from 7.5.0 to 7.6.0 removed that Sig Option. Maybe the 7.6.0 *install* didn't delete it, or maybe someone added it back after the initial upgrade from 75 to 76.

Comment: Also don't forget that this way of running scripts doesn't give you the implicit variables that you would have during a "proper" script run (as Preacher mentioned at the beginning of his answer), but that may not be an issue depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @Preacher : FYI - I edited may answer with instructions for adding the EXECUTE sig option (for running on-demand automation scripts).

Comment: Just in case someone takes it literally... Logging out and back in doesn't commit your changes. Rather, your permissions are cached when you log in. So, you log out and back in to update your cached permissions with the change you just made.

Comment: Yes, in step 4, when you create the automation script, you create it without launch points. IBM documentation uses this step to create "library" scripts, expecting you will call such scripts with `service.invokeScript("SCRIPTNAME",variablesHashMap)`.